# How do I iterate over an array with Ruby so that it saves individual records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my HTML, I am able to return an array from a select multiple box using

```
    <select multiple id="purchases" name="purchases[]">
    <option value="purchase1">Shoes</option>
    <option value="purchase2">Dress Shirts</option>
    </select>
```

My goal is to create a new database record for each of the options selected (I'm using Ruby on Rails and MySQL.) However, my controller isn't saving each value in its own record:

**Controller**

```
    @purchase = Purchase.new(params[:purchases])
    @purchase.purchaseinfo = params[:purchases]
```

**Purchase Model**

```
    class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :customer
    end
```

**Customer Model**

```
    class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :account
    has_many :purchases
    end
```

I know I should iterate through the controller, but I'm not sure how. Thanks in advance for your advice!

**Edit 1**

No matter what I do in the controller, the log tells me that the whole array, "purchases", is being sent, not the individual records. Here is the log and here is the current controller.

LOG

```
    Processing SavedcustomerController#create (for IP at DATE TIME) [POST]
    Parameters: {"purchases"=>["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]}
    Redirected to http://example.com/maptry
    Completed in 21ms (DB: 2) | 302 Found [http://example.com/]
```

SavedcustomerController#Create

```
items_array = params[:purchases].split('"\"\"",')
items_array.each do |arrayitem| 
  @purchase = Purchase.new(params[:purchases])
      @purchase.purchaseinfo = arrayitem
  end
```

Comment: Can you please add the array of information you have.  I assume that the array contains the information that corresponds with a `Purchase`?

Comment: You have `name="purchases[]"` in your HTML but you're looking at `params[:purchase]` in your Ruby?

Comment: I've added the sample data for the options; "Shoes" and "Dress Shirts" become part of the array. @muistooshort I fixed the typo. Both should be "purchases" as they are in my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Added the models. The goal of the form is to save each of the selected options from `<select multiple id="purchases" name="purchases[]">` to its own record. I'm not sure whether both of the items in the controller should be called `:purchases`. I'm trying to tell my app to save each of the name="purchases[]" options to my MySQL `purchase` table in the `purchaseinfo` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Rails 3 and you add `attr_accessible :purchase_info` to your `Purchase` model you could do this.

```
purchases = params[:purchases]
@purchases = purchases.map { |purchase| Purchase.create(purchase_info: purchase) }
```

**UPDATE**
In the most simple way you should be able to just do

```
purchases = params[:purchases]
purchases.each do |purchase_info|
  purchase = Purchase.new
  purchase.purchase_info = purchase_info
  purchase.save
end
```

I'm not sure if `attr_accessible` was in Rails 2 but that code up there should work... are you getting any exceptions/errors with the code I provided?

Comment: Sorry, not on Rails 3 yet. This is in Rails 2. Any ideas?

Comment: What ruby version are you using?

Comment: For the first code, I get this error: ` 
/path/Savedcustomer_controller.rb:90: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...rchase.create(purchase_info: purchase) } ^ /path/Savedcustomer_controller.rb:105: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting '}' /path/Savedcustomer_controller.rb:148: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting '}' `

Comment: I do not have a controller for the Purchases. Could that be a problem? I'm doing everything through SavedcustomerController.

Comment: Using your update code, I get an error `NameError (undefined local variable or method `purchases' for #<SavedCustomerController:SOMECODE>):` When I put an @ in front of purchases, I get `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: In my updated code I assumed you already had `purchases = params[:purchases]. You can do this from the `SavedcustomerController`

Comment: Man, was this huge. Thanks, Leo. I've got more, similar questions, so please keep an eye out for my activity if you get the time!

Comment: @KDP, anytime. I suggest you start moving towards Rails 3 or even Rails 4 as Rails 2 is a very old version. Ping me http://leonardocorrea.com if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
items_array = params[:purchases]
items_array.each do |arrayitem| 
  @purchase = Purchase.new()
  @purchase.purchaseinfo = arrayitem
end
```

In Purchase.new() you should put all other attributes you want